# PHP input Filtering using New 5.2, Want to change from $_POST/GET, how to sanitize these?

Tags: php, sql-injection, xss, input-filtering

I want to use the new PHP 5 > input filtering to sanitize and validate posted data, I understand how to use the filter_input function. But I dont understand exactly what I need to sanitize data for database insertion & sending an email.

Basically, I want to sanitize my data (Not validate, I understand how to do this), so that it is safe for me to handle in my backend (ie: prevents sql injection, XSS etc).

Lets say im doing this:

```
// What do I need to do to sanitize this data for SQL as best as possible.
$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array()); //Validate Example
```

[Here is a Link to the PHP filter documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) Kinda confused with so many types! Out of these, which filters do I need to use to escape ALL dangerous data. And I assume I use them in the same way as above. Is this correct?

So basically.. How do I sanitize ALL dangerous data using the new filter_input function, which of the filters from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has been asked multiple times before.

SQL injection can be prevented if you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

To prevent XSS you should not display at HTML input by users (eg convert them to HTML entities via `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` or otherwise) or aggressively whitelist tags if you want to allow HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO or a mysql escape string function will sanitize you against these.

If you have a number e.g. an ID I always cast it using `intval` so if it's anything other than a number it will be 0.